# how to assign the element of tensor from other tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to assign tensor from other tensor. i will give simple demo as followed:

```
import tensorflow as tf


input = tf.constant([1.,2.,3.],dtype=tf.float32)

test = tf.zeros(shape=(3,),dtype = tf.float32)

test[0] = input[0] 
#tf.assign(test[0],input[0])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(test)
```

I want the result of the first element of test can be equal to inputs'

The error is `Tensor object does not support item assignment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Variables support sliced assignment, while `tf.zeros` creates a constant Value tensor; You need to declare `test` as a variable:

```
sess = tf.Session()
test = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(3,),dtype = tf.float32))

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)
sess.run(test)
# array([ 0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)

assign_op = tf.assign(test[0], input[0])
sess.run(assign_op)
# array([ 1.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
sess.run(test)
# array([ 1.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```